# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I'm building a react native app and I'm using `react-native-gallery-manager` library.

Without it it works fine, but with it I get the following error:

> *What went wrong:
>
> A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-gallery-manager'.
>   Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-gallery-manager:classpath'.
>   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.jar
>        Required by:
>            project :react-native-gallery-manager

In my android/build.gradle I have the following inside buildscript:

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}
```

Does it mean I have to downgrade my gradle version?

Comment: Do you use `CameraRoll` from react-native??

Comment: Yes, I do use it

Comment: see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347#comment30

Comment: @Al-josh open [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1R0AspmhMmyA9TwSwthW7IPFsck-pZaht) link and read NOTE at the last of the Installation guide

Comment: [Here's the google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347) about this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until the library you're talking about will fix the issue, add this code to your build.gradle

```
subprojects {
    if (project.name.contains('react-native-gallery-manager')) {
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
                maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"  }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And same thing with all the libraries that have the problem... Many repo are currently being updated to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change

./node_modules/react-native-gallery-manager/android/build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
      repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
      }

    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    }
   }
```